# how to pass this array to my JQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I have this function:

```
function activateControlFlow(arrayControl) {
    $.each(arrayControl, function(){
        console.log(this);
        $(this).css({color:'#FFF', cursor: 'pointer'});  
    }); 
}
```

and I don't understand why if I pass to this function only one item, prints me that item as the array. Here is my example:

```
activateControlFlow(["a#nexth"]);
```

and in the console it prints this:

```
String {0: "a", 1: "#", 2: "n", 3: "e", 4: "x", 5: "t", 6: "h"}
```

WHY???

Comment: Can you give a example of arrayControl value being passes? are you sure its an array of dom objects?

Comment: yes It was an array of Objects, But I didn't know how to do it

Comment: A perfectly legitimate question. Just phrased in an odd way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using `this` instead of a parameter of a function, as defined in the jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
function activateControlFlow(arrayControl) {
    $.each(arrayControl, function(index, value){
        console.log(value);
        $( value ).css({color:'#FFF', cursor: 'pointer'});  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I would also suggest changing the variable's name from "`value`" to "`selector`"

Answer (score 0):

So I was using 'a#nexth' instead of $('a#nexth'), which obviously I was sending a string instead of the Object itself.

So it should be like this:

```
activateControlFlow([$('#nexth')]);
```

Comment: It might be easier not using the jQuery objects. Consider: `activateControlFlow(['#nexta', '#nextb', '#nextc'])` instead of `activateControlFlow([$('#nexta'), $('#nextb'), $('#nextc')])`